# Is there a way to get client connections count in AWS ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Is there an AWS API method (or other procedure) to determine the number of clients connected to a given Elastic Load Balancer?

Reviewing the ELB API documentation there does not seem to be a way. CloudWatch also does not seem to provide a method. Hoping to find some solutions / workarounds.

Comment: I'm curious what that number would tell you that you can't learn by looking at the number of connections from the ELB to your application server (which you can see from the app server).  Is the load balancer HTTP(S) or TCP?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Interested in TCP connections to a specific port. It seems more efficient to look at the number of connections at the ELB layer than the iterating through possibly hundreds or thousands of individual instances. I'm genuinely surprised there isn't an API method for this.

Comment: If you have hundreds or thousands of instances behind an ELB, you'll likely have a large number of invisible instances also "being" the ELB (the conventional wisdom is that ELB actually runs on EC2, which would only make sense, and would explain why it can't scale up extremely rapidly in response to traffic spikes -- instances take time to spin up)... and if such counters were exposed, that would only seem to move the polling problem you theorize into a different part of the network.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After much research it appears that the answer is - no - there is no out of the box solution provided by AWS.

However with a simple script running on each node, we can push data into CloudWatch and retrieve the data via the CloudWatch API.

```
#!/bin/bash

export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/latest

export AWS_CLOUDWATCH_HOME=/opt/aws

cd /opt/aws

./bin/mon-put-data -n 'Custom/connCounts' -m 'ConnectionCounts' -v `netstat -anp | awk '{print $4" "$6}' |grep 'PORT_NUMBER ESTABLISHED' | wc -l` --aws-credential-file /opt/aws/.ec2config
```